# Может ли начинаться предложение с "поэтому"?

Tags: вставная-конструкция

Поэтому, при переезде в новый дом первым делом хозяин приглашал туда домового.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может! Но только в том случае, когда в предыдущем контексте содержится причина того, что разъясняет предложение с местоменном наречием " поэтому". Начинать новый текст с этим наречием недопустимо.
***Ср.: Поэтому рахит ― заболевание, вызванное недостатком витамина Д ― лечат не только рыбьим жиром, но и облучением кварцевой лампой. А. М. Кузмин, «Обмен веществ и питание» // «Наука и жизнь», 1950 г. (цитата из Национального корпуса).***

Answer (score 3):

Начинаться может, ибо никаких запретов нет. А вот запятая у вас лишняя.

Answer (score 2):

[**Вопрос № 279938**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81)
Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, может ли начинаться в русском языке предложение со слова "поэтому", правомерно ли это? Пример: Согласитесь, что красиво обставленный сад привлекает внимание. Поэтому в наши дни люди стремятся облагородить придомовую территорию, сделать ее более яркой, эффектной и запоминающейся.

**Ответ** справочной службы русского языка
Начинать предложение со слова *поэтому* не запрещено.

Вот некоторые предложения, связанные с темой.
1. У домового две главные задачи — следить за домом и за скотом. **Поэтому** его можно увидеть в хлеву сидящим на яслях — кормушке для скота.
2. Одновременно следить за порядком в семье и присматривать за коровами и лошадьми тяжело даже для мифологического существа. **Поэтому** в некоторых местах России среди домашних духов произошло разделение труда.
[**Домовой**](https://rutlib6.com/book/1313/p/5)